# Does Anyone Recognize This Version of SQL?

Tags: sql, database

I've been asked to query a database through an Intersystems ODBC driver and run queries from the database on the back-end. However, it's an old off-site DB that I only have access to query and no other permissions. I have my predecessor's work and queries, but the queries are written in a form of SQL that I'm not familiar with. (See the sample below). It requires everything to be enclosed in quotes. I tried running the query without the quote marks and it gives an error.
Does anyone recognize this form of SQL? I'm looking to identify it so that I can find additional information on the code formatting.

Sample Query:

```
SELECT "WORK_ORDERS"."DATE_PLACED_IN_QUEUE"
     , "WORK_ORDERS"."ORDER_NUMBER"
     , "WORK_ORDER_TICKETS"."TICKET_STATUS"

FROM "DB"."WORK_ORDERS"
   INNER JOIN "DB"."WORK_ORDER_TICKETS"
     ON "WORK_ORDERS"."RowId" = "WORK_ORDER_TICKETS"."RowId"

WHERE "WORK_ORDERS"."DATE_PLACED_IN_QUEUE" >= {ts '2020-05-01 00:00:00'}
  AND "WORK_ORDERS"."DATE_PLACED_IN_QUEUE" < {ts '2020-05-02 00:00:00'}
```

Comment: Seems like it could be MSSQL based on the timestamp formatting seen here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @KurtKline - that's ODBC standard escape sequence (standard across multiple platforms)

Comment: Could be absolutely anything. This is just standard SQL with standard quoting for identifiers with no proprietary features

Comment: You say "it gives an error" - what is the error message? Googling that will likely tell you what the platform is

Comment: @MartinSmith: JDBC uses the same escape sequences

Comment: you could try various queries that show the database product, e.g. `select version();` or `select @@version;` or `select * from v$version` and see which one succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an InterSystems ODBC driver it is probably InterSystems Caché.

Try running

`SELECT TOP 1 $ZVERSION from Your.Table`

That should give the exact version.

Comment: InterSystems Caché supports delimited identifiers (the double quotes) but they are not normally necessary.